# Permanently disable hardware on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, webcam

I'm trying to permanently disable my webcam and bluetooth adapters on my Windows 10 HP ProBook.  I've disabled the devices, uninstalled the devices and even renamed the drivers that the devices use so they could not load.  I also configured Group Policy's 'Prevent installation of devices that match any of these device IDs' by adding the hardware IDs of these devices.

But every time there is an update these devices get re-added and re-enabled!  There are no options in my BIOS to disable them.  How do I permanently disable, remove and prevent these devices from working?

Comment: Is this a laptop? Often, if the BIOS is more flexible, you can disable these components in the BIOS. You can also disable the Bluetooth software, which would effectively block the hardware from functioning. Disabling the Bluetooth service should be simple enough, and would likely be respected by the OS.

Comment: Consider a piece of black tape over the webcam.

Comment: Already have tape on my webcam.  But it annoys me that the device continues to re enable even after I purposefully disable it.

Comment: You could always find the cable ribbon that connects the cable, it’s connected some how, ribbon is most likely.  Furthermore, BT is easy to disable, pull the card out

Comment: @music2myear did not try the service route so I'll see if that sticks.  But just trying to disable BluetoothUserService_a2a80 causes a "the parameter is incorrect." error.  Seems like Windows won't allow it to be disabled (not easily at least).

Comment: @Ramhound This is a laptop.  No easily accessible ribbon but it may come to that.

Comment: Your question didn’t specify an easy solution, but you also indicated the easy solution (to disable and block the driver) wasn’t working

Comment: @Ramhound Windows update reinstalled the driver even though the device was disabled in Device Manager and the driver was renamed (added a .bak extension).  Basically Windows doesn't seem to care about device settings.  Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @user2021 - You have to block the driver update, there is a tool that exists, and Windows Update installing drivers isn’t a bug.  Disabling a device has never blocked a driver from being installed on Windows

Comment: @Ramhound I shouldn't have to use a third-party tool to keep a device disabled.  If Windows Update wants to update the driver that's fine but it shouldn't re-enable the device if it has been disabled.  That's a bug or just a big FU by Microsoft.

Comment: It’s not a third-party tool,

Comment: This is the likely tool, and instructions, Ramhound is referring to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-driver-update-from-reinstalling-in-windows-10-17df0ef3-7480-36e9-0ed9-118351398897

Answer (score 1):

- From the Device Manager right click on the device that you want to permanently disable.
- Select Properties.
- Select Events and then Select View All Events.
- From the Actions column in the Event Viewer.
- Select Properties.
- Select Edit Filter.
- Change the Query Id="0" to a "1" or vice versa.

This solution is based on personal experience with an X41 ThinkPad Tablet running Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB to permanently disable the unsupported Video Controller.